# How to set container IP address when using PyCharm Docker plugin

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, pycharm, containers

I have a python project that runs in a docker container.

There is a **docker-compose.yml** file which gives it a network and IP address as follows:

```
networks:
    my-network:
        ipv4_address: 172.10.0.1
```

When my container starts up it will have this address (And other containers can communicate with it)

I can launch this container using PyCharm and its Docker plugin.

I can set various environment variables in PyCharms **Debug Configurations-->Docker Container Settings**

How can I pass in an IP address so that its used by the running container when I start it up in PyCharm?

Comment: You should almost never need to manually set that address.  In most commonly-available environments it will be unreachable from outside Docker, and between containers on the same Docker network you can use the container name as a host name.  Unless you have some really specific needs, it will probably work to outright delete all of the `networks:` blocks in the whole file.  Also see [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation.

Comment: I am working with an existing docker-compose file that has the ipv4_address set for each container, so I am trying to just get the debugger working.  I understand its not the way it 'should be'  Do you know how I can set the IP address of a container that I spin up in PyCharm?